# Spring WebFlux + Kotlin Response Handling

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around a supposedly simple RESTful WS response handling scenario when using Spring WebFlux in combination with Kotlin coroutines. Suppose we have a simple WS method in our REST controller that is supposed to return a possibly huge number (millions) of response "things":

```
@GetMapping
suspend fun findAllThings(): Flow<Thing> {
    //Reactive DB query, return a flow of things
}
```

This works as one would expect: the result is streamed to the client as long as a streaming media type (e.g. "application/x-ndjson") is used. In more complex service calls that also accounts for the possibility of errors/warnings I would like to return a response object of the following form:

```
class Response<T> {
    val errors: Flow<String>
    val things: Flow<T>
}
```

The idea here being that a response either is successful (returning an empty error Flow and a Flow of things), or failed (errors contained in the corresponding Flow while the things Flow being empty). In blocking programming this is a quite common response idiom. My question now is how can I adapt this idiom to the reactive approach in Kotlin/Spring WebFlux?

I know its possible to just return the Response as described (or Mono<Response> for Java users), but this somewhat defeats the purpose of being reactive as the entire Mono has to exist in memory at serialization time. Is there any way to solve this? The only possible solution I can think of right now is a custom Spring Encoder that is smart enough to stream both errors or things (whatever is present).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about returning Success/Error per `Thing`?

```kotlin
class Result<T> private constructor(val result: T?, val error: String?) {

    constructor(data: T) : this(data, null)
    constructor(error: String) : this(null, error)
    val isError = error != null

}

@GetMapping
suspend fun findAllThings(): Flow<Result<Thing>> {
    //Reactive DB query, return a flow of things
}
```

Comment: Hm, that is an interesting approach that would solve my problem. As a (minor) downside it would make response handling a bit more complex, but it does solve the streaming problem. Another idea I came up with was simply throwing an exception on the server side. I guess this would fit the "onError()" idiom of reactive Publishers quite well. The disadvantage would be that I'll loose access to more structured error information I might have on the server - think error object instead of just a simple String.

Comment: I have marked this answer as accepted - it seems to be the best state-of-the-art solution. Further investigation showed that there are quite a few situations where reactive streaming does either not work exactly as I would have expected, or simply does not provide great benefits that make it worthwhile. Example: streaming complex object hierarchies where the root objects are light-weight, but nested objects are huge are not streamed efficiently: 

class Thing(val name: String, val children: Flow<Child>) // Each child object takes ~1MB RAM

Comment: Just to make one thing clear: reactive streams (i.e. WebFlux vs Spring MVC) are not about streaming responses from server at all, although thay can help with that. They are first of all about non-blocking processing and resource usage optimization. Definitelly not all APIs are good candidates for streaming, but all can benefit from reactive stack.